The deployed contract bytecode does not match the compiled bytecode
first some context, I am building a Go-Ethereum tool that can compile, deploy, verify and finally run some functions on the deployed contract on Sepolia. It works fine with the exception of the verification step. But when I copy and paste the Solidity code into Etherscan for verification it works.
The code required to replicate the process is pretty extensive so I decided to put is on Github instead of here Github repo.
Just clone, see the README.md.
My question is what is the Go code failing to verify the deployed contract when it can be verified manually on Etherscan.
